# How to set focus on a disabled dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html

Disabled attribute is being dynamically added to my dropdown list. How do I set focus to dropdown list without removing disabled attribute. Is it possible to set the focus? The purpose of setting focus is for screen reader to read the dropdown list and let the user know that it is a disabled dropdown.

I tried using read-only attribute but it doesn't work on dropdown list. Below is the html for dropdown:

```
<select name="description" id="description" disabled="disabled" class="disabledSelection largeGroup">
  <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">Montana</option>
  <option value="2">Utah</option>
</select>
```

My another question is my dropdown list has 3 options, how to remove 2 of the options except the default selected one based on certain conditions( if dropdown is disabled show only default value). I am using the below jQuery code but it's not working.

```
$('#description').each(function () {
  if ($(this).is('select')) {
    $('option', this).not(':Selected').remove();
  }  
});
```

Comment: Disabled DOM elements cannot have the focus. Your best bet is to remove the "disabled" attribute for the duration of your operation.

Comment: I don't want the user to select the particular dropdown unless he fills few other details. But i want to show that disabled dropdown in UI. If i don't disable it he will be able to select it. How can i convey that it is disabled without using disabled attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do anything when the `disabled` attribute is there.

But, if you record the `select` states (which `option` is selected) at a given time, you can freeze it like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var myotherCondition = false;
  var selectedOptions = [];

  // Get the selected indexes in an array.
  for (i=0;i<$("select").length;i++){
    selectedOptions.push( $("select").eq(i)[0].selectedIndex );
  }
  console.log( JSON.stringify(selectedOptions) );

  $("select").on("change",function(){

    // If the other condition is fulfilled, this is a normal select behaviour.
    if(myotherCondition){
      console.log("Change accepted.");

      // If the other condition is NOT fulfilled, drop list opens... But changes don't stay.
    }else{
      console.log("Change not accepted, sorry.");

      var thisEQ = $(this).index();      
      $(this).find("option").prop("selected",false);
      $(this).find("option").eq(selectedOptions[thisEQ]).prop("selected",true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="description" id="description" class="disabledSelection largeGroup">
  <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">Montana</option>
  <option value="2">Utah</option>
</select>
```

About your second question on removing unselected options, this simple as:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('option').not(':selected').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="description" id="description" class="disabledSelection largeGroup">
  <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">Montana</option>
  <option value="2">Utah</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated before, you can't use the "disabled" attribute for this. However, this can be accomplished very easily without having to store the previous value.

This snippet will disable clicking on the dropdown as well as prevent changing via keypress, while still allowing the user to tab in and out.

```js
// Set aria-disabled to true in order to signify to screen readers that the control is unavailable
$('#description').attr('aria-disabled', 'true');
// Disable clicking on the control
$("#description").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
// Disable changing the value via keyboard
$("#description").on('keydown', function (e) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    // Only disable if the keycode is not TAB
    if (keycode != 9)
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="description" id="description">
  <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">Montana</option>
  <option value="2">Utah</option>
</select>
```

As for the second part of the question, the proper way to remove all but the selected option from a specific dropdown is to do:

```js
$('#description').find('option').not(':selected').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="description" id="description">
  <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">Montana</option>
  <option value="2">Utah</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I hope this can still help.
You can use `aria-disabled` attribute instead of `disabled`, and your element will be able to be assigned focus (even in IE and mobile, usually this problem doesn't rise in Chrome or Edge).

As a side note, if you also want your element to be navigable with keyboard TAB, of course make sure to set tabindex="0" (however this is not needed for programmatically assign focus via JavaScript).